# htaccess issues and rewrite cond

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my current script... I need to allow "sub.domain.com/register/USER"

Currently, I have a rerwrite cond for "sub.domain.com" which points right to "sub.domain.com/login"

What am I doing wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^register(.*) https://%1.domain.com/register$1 [L,R=302,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://%1.domain.com/login/ [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

As of update, I have a redirect loop in /register/USER..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your first set of rules with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+).domain.com$
RewriteRule ^register(.*) - [L,R=302,QSA]
```

**EDIT**: Maybe a better solution is to rewrite only if the URI isn't /register/user. So get rid of the above rule, and change the one below it to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  !^www.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   ^(.+).domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/register/?.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1.domain.com/login/ [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Yes that would be a loop. Try now?

Comment: Actually, it does not work.  In your logic it will only work with register.  I need "sub.domain.com" to go to /login/.. and "sub.domain.com/register/user" to go there.

Comment: /register/user to go where? What this rule does is it first checks that the HTTP host doesn't start with www, then grabs the part before domain.com, then says if the URI begins with register, then don't do any rewriting and allow it to go there.

Comment: Seems like /login/ and /register/user/ works.. but, www.domain.com/home does not work.  Any idea?

Comment: Added the www exception in the answer.

Comment: I already had that.. Very weird problem.  On a Mac (Chrome/FF), all works well.  On a PC (FF/IE) work fine, but Chrome on PC does not?  Plus, it constantly loggs me out in IE on a PC.  Could that be related?

Comment: Hmm these rewrites are server side so it shouldn't affect your client experience.

Comment: Ansari, I couldn't thank you enough.  Really appreciate your help.